# Compare the following numbers...

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can I compare this two numbers: $\tan \frac 7{10}$ and $1$?

Hope your explanation will be as explicit as possible! Thank you very much!

Comment: What is $tg0,7$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Sorry in my country it's so taught to be.

Comment: So, it's $\tan(7/10)$, yes?

Comment: yes it's so ....

Answer (score 4):

The tangent function is an increasing function on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Also, $\frac{7}{10} < \frac{3}{4} < \frac{\pi}{4}$, so $\tan(7/10) < \tan(\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since on the interval $\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2},-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$ the function $\tan(x)$ has positive slope, if $a>b,\tan(a)>\tan(b)\forall a,b\in\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2},-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Therefore, since $\dfrac{7}{10}<\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=1$, we may say that
$$\tan\left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)<\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Comment: $0,7$ is alternate form for $0.7$. Some locales swap "$.$" and "$,$" in number representations.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh. Didn't know that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See my edit.

Comment: For some reason, despite the significant edit, I can't remove my downvote. Irritating. Sorry.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No problem - I don't take downvotes personally! :-)